# Setup openvpn in an Ubuntu act as both client and server to connect to another server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

This is what I want to do:

> connect to server 1.1.1.1 via ssh, then in 1.1.1.1 run `openvpn --config file /path/file.ovpn` to connect to 2.2.2.2 but only incoming traffic from port 1194 should go to tun0 device.

When I run this command, in fact the default routing changes and I cannot access to 1.1.1.1 anymore (I should kill that PID via console).

I want to establish connection but shouldn't change default routing. I mean OpenVPN's connection should be open but only any traffic comes from port 1194 should go through `tun0` device, and other traffic like port 80 and 587 should go through `eth0`.

I googled but couldn't find proper way or any ways.

The image below is something I just drew to try to show my mean better:

[image]

I want to know how to configure it so that it can act both as a client and server, and has a persistent connection from 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2 as a client, and I with my mobile connect to 1.1.1.1. as client to OpenVPN Server 1.1.1.1.

I'm not much experienced in this field but I'm curious to know whether it is possible and if yes, how?

Thanks in advance